# Displaying all layers in ArcGIS feature service in Angular application

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer, feature-service, angular

As you can see in the below living atlas layer, there are multiple layers inside (state,county,tract etc..)

But when I add **https://services2.arcgis.com/FiaPA4ga0iQKduv3/arcgis/rest/services/US_Census_Age_Gender/FeatureServer** this link it will display only the first layer.(State).Then, when I zoom in the map, that layer disappears.

I want to display all the 4 layers of that feature service.(state,county,tract,blockgroups)

How do I achieve this?

**.ts file**

```
const genderLayer = new FeatureLayer({
    url: "https://services2.arcgis.com/FiaPA4ga0iQKduv3/ArcGIS/rest/services/US_Census_Age_Gender/FeatureServer",
    });
    const layersToCreateMyPopupTemplate = [ageLayer,genderLayer];

const map = new Map({
      basemap: 'topo-vector',
      layers: layersToCreateMyPopupTemplate
  });

    const view = new MapView({
      container,
      map: map,
      zoom: 3,
      center: [-97.63, 38.34],
    });
```

**.html**

```
<!-- Map Div -->
<div #mapViewNode></div>
```

Comment: Hi @PolyGeo I've updated the question. Can you please help me?

Comment: I don’t work with the ArcGIS API for JavaScript so I’m not a potential answerer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that service has a "visibility based on scale" configuration.
With [maxScale](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#maxScale) and [minScale](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#minScale) properties in the FeatureLayer constructor, you may be able to override this behavior.
Also, Your layers are very opaque, so you may need to play with their opacity to see them all together.